# Pandas dataframe divide value by matching value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A that looks like this

```
bucket  value   
1       0.001855    
1       0.000120    
2       0.000042    
2       0.001888
```

and a dataframe B that looks like this

```
bucket  num 
1       .5  
2       .3
```

I want to create a column in A that has all value divided by num in B matched by bucket. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** answers the following question from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290932/pandas-dataframe-divide-value-by-matching-value-in-another-dataframe/41290954#comment69785074_41290954):

> What if A is a multiindex? With ['bucket1','bucket2'] as index but we
>   only care for bucket1?

```
In [140]: A
Out[140]:
                    value
bucket1 bucket2
1       10       0.001855
        11       0.000120
2       12       0.000042
        13       0.001888

In [141]: B
Out[141]:
   bucket  num
0       1  0.5
1       2  0.3

In [142]: A['new'] = A.value / A.reset_index().iloc[:, 0].map(B.set_index('bucket').num).values

In [143]: A
Out[143]:
                    value       new
bucket1 bucket2
1       10       0.001855  0.003710
        11       0.000120  0.000240
2       12       0.000042  0.000140
        13       0.001888  0.006293
```

**OLD answer:**

you can use [Series.map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
In [61]: A['new'] = A.value.div(A.bucket.map(B.set_index('bucket').num))

In [62]: A
Out[62]:
   bucket     value       new
0       1  0.001855  0.003710
1       1  0.000120  0.000240
2       2  0.000042  0.000140
3       2  0.001888  0.006293
```

or as a **virtual** column:

```
In [60]: A.assign(new=A.value/A.bucket.map(B.set_index('bucket').num))
Out[60]:
   bucket     value       new
0       1  0.001855  0.003710
1       1  0.000120  0.000240
2       2  0.000042  0.000140
3       2  0.001888  0.006293
```

Explanation:

```
In [65]: B.set_index('bucket')
Out[65]:
        num
bucket
1       0.5
2       0.3

In [66]: A.bucket.map(B.set_index('bucket').num)
Out[66]:
0    0.5
1    0.5
2    0.3
3    0.3
Name: bucket, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What if A is a multiindex? With ['bucket1','bucket2'] as index but we only care for bucket1? I am getting No axis named 2 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> as an error

Comment: @SuperString, can you post __reproducible__ sample data sets and expected data set? Pleas read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @SuperString in all fairness, that is the sort of thing you bring up in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really just admiring @MaxU's answer and wanted to contribute something.
Here is a numpy answer

```
A.value /= B.num.values.dot(B.bucket.values[:, None] == A.bucket.values)

A

   bucket     value
0       1  0.003710
1       1  0.000240
2       2  0.000140
3       2  0.006293
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as efficient, but you could also use `merge` to properly distribute values of num in dfB across dfA and then use element-wise division at the index level. to calculate these values.

```
dfA['new'] = dfA['value'] / pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on='bucket')['num']

dfA
   bucket     value       new
0       1  0.001855  0.003710
1       1  0.000120  0.000240
2       2  0.000042  0.000140
3       2  0.001888  0.006293
```